# egrep: Unmatched ( or \(

Tags: grep

I'm trying to run this command to do some cleanups.

```
egrep -v -f ref_file.css my_file.css
```

However, it is giving me an error.

egrep: Unmatched ( or \ (

How can I go around that? I'm on mac terminal.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: `egrep -f` tries to us the immediately following file as a set of grep patterns (one per line, if memory serves). It sounds like your `ref_file.css` contains at least one line that doesn't form a valid grep pattern (specifically, one with mismatched parens). Since you haven't shown us the content of the file, it's hard to guess what it does contain though. Based on the name, it sounds like it contains CSS, not grep patterns at all.

Comment: If you're just trying to find the differences between the two files, you might want to consider using `diff` instead (though there are *many* alternatives to `diff` as well).

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes I'm trying to compare 2 css files. I'll look into diff options. Regular diff is returning some crazy result.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late, but maybe this can help other users looking for the same...

If you just want to check the differences between two files, then you can use `diff`, as mentioned in the comments.  However, if the files are somewhat similar, and you are looking for a way to check the differences *visually*, then you can use `sdiff file1 file2` to get a `diff`-ish output but showing the files side by side.

In the output, `|` between the two files means that the line is somewhat shared between the two files, but with differences in the text or format.

`<` and `>` means that the line to the left or to the right exists in the left or the right file, and not in the other, as you may have expected.

You may then grep the output from `sdiff` for `' | '`, `' < '`, and `' > '`, and analize that in case you need to do further processing on the files...